# It comprises that which composes it

Tags: wordplay, graph-theory

[image: comprises_and_composes]

**Text version:**

```
           GRINNING              SUCCESSES       INITIATION               RESELLERS               INITIATING                SLEEVELESS                CONCOCTION               SASSAFRAS       IGNITING             ASSESSES
---------            ----------             ---              -----------             -----------              ------------              ------------              -----------             ---            ---------
|SEARING|------------|SECURING|-------------|?|--------------|RELATIONS|-------------|TRIANGLES|--------------|EVANGELIST|--------------|NOVELISTIC|--------------|FRACTIONS|-------------|?|------------|SEATING|------------>> (wraparound)
---------            ----------             ---              -----------             -----------              ------------              ------------              -----------             ---            ---------
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Each word on an edge comprises 4-5 unique letters. Each word on a vertex comprises all of the letters, and only the letters, of the words on the two adjacent edges. By this logic, the two missing words are **STRAFING** and **TENACIOUS**.
>  `seaRING - GINR - secuRING - cesu - TeNAcIOus - AINOT - relATIONs - elrs - TrIANGles - AGINT - evANGelIsT - elsv - NOvelIsTIC - CINOT - fraCTIONs - afrs - sTrafING - GINT - seaTING - aes - seaRING`

Comment: s/is comprised of/comprises/g